# Python printing and textwrapping

Tags: python, submission

I have a question regarding printing in Python. I use the following for printing

I want to generate a bash script using python 3.7.

```
res="""\
    {someline} some more code some keywords etc 
""".format(someline = self.someline)

res = textwrap.dedent(res)
```

This I use for getting the text in a format that it autmatically prints newlines etc.

But if I now have in my string a lot of arguments, the line gets longer and longer. But if i press enter, I get a newline.

So is there a way to have a wordwrap without having a new line for better 
readability in the code?

Comment: Don't use `"""` it is not meant for that, and just end the line with `\ ` without ending the quotes. It allows your code to span over several lines.

Comment: Hmm okay so what should I use instead?

Comment: Regular qutoes (`"`) or ticks (`'`) the `"""` is used for doc strings

Answer (score 0):

```
print("\
This will get printed\
, and this will be on the same line\
")
```

When using normal quotes, as in `"` or `'`, ending a line with a backslash then starting a new line will continue the string over to the next line and not create a new line, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to say, it's in the end not about printing, but about writing into a file with f.write(res).

Comment: Well it should be the same process.